# Python Tkinter text size

Tags: python, tkinter

I only started to learn how to build GUIs. Is there any way to set the size of the textbox?
I tried to use `.geometry`, but it was wrong:

```py
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("boop")
root.geometry("500x700")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

msg = Text(app)
# msg.geometry("500x50") - this is what i tried, and was wrong.
msg.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done by using the `height` and `width` options:

```
# I just picked 50 and 500 to demonstrate
# You can tweak it to your needs
msg = Text(app, height=50, width=500)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working.
But i don't understate the measuring units, doesn't look like pixels or centimeters.

Comment: @KostyaKishnevsky - I have heard that the units are text units, or, namely, how much space it takes to type a monospace letter.

Comment: @Zipzap: the width and height attributes are based on the average width of a character in the font used by the widget. More specifically, I believe it is the width of the character "0" (zero). It should also be mentioned that setting the geometry (via `root.geometry(...)`) will potentially override the requested size of the widget.